# Cannot merge two partition together after dividing partition for installing Linux

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I tried to install Linux after dividing partition. However, when I tried to merge the partition after erasing the partition with the error shown in the image below, I could not merge together. Can somebody help with my problem?

[image]

```
opilseung@172-15-7-158 ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC ⁨⁩                        524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk4⁩         442.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                        EFI ⁨EFI - LINUX⁩             500.2 MB   disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         51.4 GB    disk0s4
   5:        Apple_APFS_Recovery ⁨⁩                        5.4 GB     disk0s5

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +51.4 GB    disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s4
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨소설 및 만화⁩            36.9 KB    disk3s1

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +442.5 GB   disk4
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     44.1 GB    disk4s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.2 GB    disk4s3
   3:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.2 GB    disk4s3s1
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 333.1 MB   disk4s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                798.0 MB   disk4s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk4s6
```

Comment: Can you please run `diskutil list` in Terminal and add the output as text?

Comment: Please add that as text not an image so that we can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands are given below. Here, I assume you do not want `disk0s3` or `disk0s4` and want to expand `disk0s2` to include the space occupied by `disk0s3` and `disk0s4`.

```
diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s4 TempName
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: I was really stressing with this. Thank You!!